# Microsoft.Identity.Client fails in .Net Core app

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I downloaded the console-csharp-snippets-sample. I think it's a desktop console app and it runs fine with my client id. To authenticate, it uses the following:

> using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
>
> public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(clientIdForUser);
>
> authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Scopes, IdentityClientApp.Users.First());

Now, I'm trying to write the same but in a .Net Core console app. It crashes at the third line with error:

> Error getting /me user One or more errors occurred. (The method or operation is not implemented.) The method or operation is not implemented.

The reason is because this time it's not finding me as a user. I changed First() to Count() and printed it out and it came back zero.

Can someone tell me how to authenticate in a dotnet core console app?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 1.1.0-preview version of the Microsoft.Identity.Client NuGet package?

It seems to be the first one that supports .NET Standard.

The `NotImplementedException` could be from an API that Microsoft.Identity.Client expects to be implemented but isn't because your app is a .NET Core application.

Comment: Yes, it is 1.1.0-preview. It seems the method First() is not available, however, it runs fine in the original desktop app version.

Comment: After testing by changing First() to Count() and printing it out, it came back zero, so it's not that First() is not available as previously thought.